# Compare Message_read From Arduino

Tags: string, bluetooth, message, equals

I receive data from Arduino, but the data appears as "String", when I want to compare the data as "int".

Example:
On the ListView from my app, the readMessage , I see 10, on my app. <==== Not sure

I want this behaviour:

```
if readMessage >0 and <=100
    My app sends the message "Hello"

if readMessage >=100 and <=200
    My app sends a message "Try again"
```

I used "equals", but it's only for a status, and my app changes in real time, so it is not working for me.

```
case MESSAGE_READ:
    byte[] readBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
    // construct a string from the valid bytes in the buffer
    String readMessage = new String(readBuf, 0, msg.arg1);

    mConversationArrayAdapter.add("Nivel de alcohol"+":  " + readMessage);

    if (readMessage.equals("100")) {
        mensaje.setText("1.0 g/l en aliento, Aliento alcohólico, disminución mínima de los sentidos");
    }
    else if (readMessage.equals("300")) {
        mensaje.setText("2.4 g/l en aliento, Ebriedad incompleta, disminución significativa de los sentidos.Se recomienda interrumpir cualquier actividad física de riesgo.");
    }
    else if (readMessage.equals("400")) {
        mensaje.setText("3.8 g/l en aliento, Ebriedad completa en la mayoría de los estados de la República Mexicana");
    }
    else if (readMessage.equals("500")) {
        mensaje.setText("4.8 g/l en aliento, Limite BAC más alto aceptado en pocos países");
    }
    else if (readMessage.equals("600")) {
        mensaje.setText("15.0 g/l en aliento,A este nivel la mayoría de las personas pierden la conciencia");
    }

    break;
```

Comment: Hi Devilbeasts - welcome to StackOverflow. I am having a bit of trouble understanding what you are asking. Also, your code seems to be half missing. I will try to fix as much of it as possible, but you will need to change my changes!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best thing to do here is to try to convert `readMessage` to an integer, and then compare that integer to your different numbers. The parseInt() method tries to do the conversion, throwing an exception if it fails.

```
case MESSAGE_READ:
    byte[] readBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
    // construct a string from the valid bytes in the buffer
    String readMessage = new String(readBuf, 0, msg.arg1);

    mConversationArrayAdapter.add("Nivel de alcohol"+":  " + readMessage);

    try {
        // Convert the string to an integer. It may fail (see the catch block).
        int messageNumber = Integer.parseInt(readMessage);

        if (messageNumber == 100) {
            mensaje.setText("1.0 g/l en aliento, Aliento alcohólico, disminución mínima de los sentidos");
        }
        else if (messageNumber == 300) {
            mensaje.setText("2.4 g/l en aliento, Ebriedad incompleta, disminución significativa de los sentidos.Se recomienda interrumpir cualquier actividad física de riesgo.");
        }
        else if (messageNumber == 400) {
            mensaje.setText("3.8 g/l en aliento, Ebriedad completa en la mayoría de los estados de la República Mexicana");
        }
        else if (messageNumber == 500) {
            mensaje.setText("4.8 g/l en aliento, Limite BAC más alto aceptado en pocos países");
        }
        else if (messageNumber == 600) {
            mensaje.setText("15.0 g/l en aliento,A este nivel la mayoría de las personas pierden la conciencia");
        }
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException)
    {
        // If you got here, then readMessage was not a valid integer. You should add some error handling here.
    }
    break;
```

Comment: Hi , thanks , i'm trying do it, but the messages dont change :/

Comment: Well, considering *you* wrote the messages, you shouldn't be caring about them. Aren't you going to see what readMessage and messageNumber look like?

Comment: sorry, i having a problem, i receive random  data , if i receive "Hello", first appear "H" in a line , then "ello", i dont know why, i'm using Bluetooth Chat from eclipse examples.